# Swift 2.0:Data not being displayed from Parse through prepareForSegue method

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, segue

I'm trying to pass data between my `HomeViewController` and `ReplyViewController` through my `prepareForSegue` but it is not displaying on the next page. I think my code is right in my `HomeViewController` but incorrect in my `viewDidLoad` of my `ReplyViewController`. How can I display the data onto the next page with my method for `prepareForSegue`?

This is my `prepareForSegue` in my `HomeViewController`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "mySegue"){
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let obj = self.objects![indexPath!.row] as! PFObject
            let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let infoVC = navVC.topViewController as! ReplyViewController
            infoVC.commentPost = obj
        }
    }
```

Here is my `ReplyViewController`:

```
var commentPost = PFObject?
/* TOP cell: User post */


    @IBOutlet weak var messageDetails: UILabel?

    /* TOP cell: User post */
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    print(commentPost)
    print(commentPost?.objectForKey("details"))
    self.messageDetails!.text = commentPost?.objectForKey("details") as? String


}
```

Comment: r u using segue in storyboard ? or r u calling it somewhere in the code ?

Comment: from where did comment VC came from ?

Comment: You're post says you want to pass data to your `ReplyViewController`, and that it doesn't show in your `CommentsViewController`? It seems like you set the data correctly in `prepareForSegue` in a `ReplyViewController`, but your bottom code is for a `CommetnsViewController`? Have you got your views mixed up?

Comment: Yeah I just made a mistake in my post. I edited it just now

Comment: This is strange. Your code looks good Have you added a print("called") within your PrepareForSegue to make sure that that logic is getting called? That'd be the most likely thing to me.

Comment: Code looks good to me, is your segue identifier in your storyboard definitely `'mySegue'`? If not, it won't enter that `if` block.

Comment: Segue identifiers are case sensitive as well, so make sure they match each other exactly.

Comment: No I ran my app again though and it's displaying the data now, however, not the correct data I wanted segued.